# Protect against possible malicious downvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

First of all, I am not a person who cares reputation scores. But the recent sequence of downvotes on my questions may indicate personal attacks from some user.

Following is a screenshot from [my reputation history](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/1258/tim?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time)

[image]

I wonder what can be done about this? Even if this kind of behavior is deemed to be fine, I won't feel too bad, but only sorry for the person who enjoys having negative feeling.

Thanks in advance for your concern.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Can you update after couple of days if this got rectified. Surprised to see this kind of behaviour on our site.

Comment: It's possible someone took exception to the type of questions you were asking.  The downvotes do target very similar types of questions, which could be considered only marginally related to personal finance.

Comment: @Renesis: Why are they marginally related to personal finance? What SE site are they related to?

Comment: I too recently saw this behavior with my questions. I just deleted them. Only one person told me why they down voted (and I suppose he was correct). All my previous questions were down voted and also my new ones would immediately get down voted.  It seems like you can only ask 401K or IRA related questions without getting down votes. Just my experience.

Comment: I wasn't behind these downvotes, but there have been times on other SE sites that I've read a bad question and looked at the profile of the user to see if it is a habit or one-off before downvoting. If it is a habit I sometimes go downvote their other questions, but only if they are also bad not as an attack on the user directly.

Answer (score 6):

There is a daily process that detects and removes statistically anomalous voting patterns every day.

**If the problem persists for more than 24-36 hours**, feel free to email the address at the bottom of every page -- or flag a relevant post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are automated tools that monitor for vote fraud.  The details of which are deliberately kept quiet to prevent people from manipulating the system.

Hopefully, someone employed at StackOverflow can weigh in with more details.